# Выбрать одно из заданных слов

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Мне нужно определить в строке *одно из N* заданных слов. Для примера возьмём такие: `zero`, `.one`, `two`

Частично с этим помогает справиться такое выражение:

```
/\b(?:zero|\.one|two)\b/
```

Но есть одна проблема: оно не определяет `.one`, так как оно начинается с не-word символа (`.`)

Как же должно выглядеть правильное выражение для данного случая?

Comment: И вне вопроса: посоветуйте хорошую литературу по регуляркам, пожалуйста. А то уже лет пять не доходят руки с ними разобраться от и до, так что их понимание у меня зиждется на моей интуиции хД

Comment: https://karmazzin.gitbooks.io/eloquentjavascript_ru/

Comment: @Air: премного благодарен!)

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, мне пока хватает погружения в регулярки того, что приводят в своей книге Албахари (C# X.X. Справочник. Полное описание языка)

Comment: @АндрейNOP: о, тоже верно) Я грешным делом всегда как-то пропускал главы про regex с мыслями: *"Правильнее будет руками реализовать под конкретную задачу"*) Но вот, бывают задачи, где возможно использовать только регулярки ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Всегда (наверное) можно заменить регулярку ручным парсингом, вопрос в том, во сколько раз становится запутаннее, сложнее и объемнее код. Хотя, с регулярками тоже можно такого наворотить... :D

Comment: @АндрейNOP: когда код полностью твой - безусловно. Поэтому я так посредственно к теме и относился. Но иногда от тебя как раз таки требуют не код, а регулярное выражение ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Дело в том, что регулярное выражение `\b\.one\b` может быть самопротиворечиво, т.к. граница слова здесь уже есть и она между точкой и буквой `o`: `.one`, это выражение сработает только если будет еще одна граница слова слева от точки, например: `some.one`, нужно ли вам это? Я не знаю.

Таким образом вам придется начать с чего-то вроде:

```
(?:\bzero\b|\.one\b|\btwo\b)
```

и потом, возможно, добавить отрицательный просмотр назад:

```
(?:\bzero\b|(?<!\b)\.one\b|\btwo\b)
```

ну и в итоге можно будет немного сократить до чего-то вроде:

```
(?:\b(zero|two)|(?<!\b)\.one)\b
```

тест: https://regex101.com/r/IkeH4m/1

Comment: Таки нужно и сие я уже заметил) Хм. А это выражение не сработает, случайно, для, скажем `test.one`?

Comment: Сработает. Как раз показал как это исправить

Comment: А, все, вот это не должно) Спасибо Вам большое!

Comment: таки да, я писал в то время, как Вы параллельно обновляли ответ хД

Comment: Посмотрите тест, всем ли условиям удовлетворяет

Comment: да, спасибо ещё раз! Как раз то, что нужно